# How to check if a function is deprecated using NeoVim Lua api

Tags: neovim, lua

I'm currently working on neovim plugins that use vim functions through the Lua API. However, I'm not sure how to determine if a particular Vim API function is deprecated or not using the Lua API. For example, vim.pretty_print now shows a deprecation message every time I use it (which is annoying for the end user), but this only happens in latest vim.

I would be grateful if someone could guide me on how to check if a Vim API function is deprecated using the Lua API.

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance.